# How to improve lazy delegate?

Tags: kotlin, delegated-properties

How i can improve this declaration:

```
val __name: String by lazy {
     createHTML().small {
         +name
     }
}
```

like as my own delegate builder `html`:

```
val __name: String by html {
    small {
        +name
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is necessarily an _improvement_ as much as it shortens code length

Comment: @Moira yes, it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want a function `html`, wrapping `lazy` and returning a `Lazy<T>`:

```
fun html(builder: Html.() -> Unit) = lazy { createHtml().builder() }
```

(I don't know the type returned by `createHtml`, so I'm assuming it's called `Html`.)

I'm not sure this is good design, however, since it loses the semantic value of `lazy`, and because it only really serves to save a few characters, but this is just my opinion.